# env-cmd Failed to find .rc file at default paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, env-cmd

I am using the tool [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd) to manage my environment variables, and am encountering the error:

> Error: Failed to find .rc file at default paths: [./.env-cmdrc,./.env-cmdrc.js,./.env-cmdrc.json]

I have verified that the file (in my case `./.env-cmdrc`) does exist in the working directory and has sufficient permissions `644` (anyone can read). The file also contains the expected values.

This is **not** a result of using the wrong flag/syntax to find the env file as other questions are.

The command being ran is formatted as `env-cmd -e ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Why is this error thrown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this library throws this misleading error in a few different cases when the file is actually present.

##### Malformed JSON in the env file

A commonly reported source of this error is invalid JSON in the file. ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd/issues/127)). Trailing commas are common, but it could be from a variety of causes.

##### Missing environment in env file

When using an env-cmdrc file with multiple environments (see [Advanced Usage](https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd#-advanced-usage)), this error is thrown when the environment specified in the command is not present in the file.

In my case, I was using a variable to determine the target environment which was `undefined`, resulting in `env-cmd -e undefined`. The JSON did not have a key called `undefined` which causes the error to be thrown.

---

These are the only two scenarios I have found that illegitimately cause this error so far. The library has not been updated in 3 years, so it seems unlikely that it will be fixed.